# Failed to load template on gulp dist build

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gulp

We are using a directive that allows users to input their date of birth. This works absolutely fine on the local gulp dev build, however when we move across to a distribution build, it says this template cannot be found. There are no errors in the gulp:dist process or errors in console when using the directive in a local dev build

Here is the error message from the dist build

```
GET http://localhost:3000/app/_common/form-dob/form-dob.tpl.html 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ generated.js:20178l @ generated.js:62054v @ generated.js:19971c @ generated.js:19681u @ generated.js:24202(anonymous function) @ generated.js:24218h.$eval @ generated.js:25462h.$digest @ generated.js:25280h.$apply @ generated.js:25570o @ generated.js:20002g @ generated.js:20200w.onload @ generated.js:20141
generated.js:21933 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /app/_common/form-dob/form-dob.tpl.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Fapp%2F_common%2Fform-dob%2Fform-dob.tpl.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at generated.js:9279
    at s (generated.js:27164)
    at u (generated.js:24202)
    at generated.js:24218
    at h.$eval (generated.js:25462)
    at h.$digest (generated.js:25280)
    at h.$apply (generated.js:25570)
    at o (generated.js:20002)
    at g (generated.js:20200)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (generated.js:20141)
```

Is there a specific reason for this? Can't seem to find any invalid JavaScript in the file.

The directive is very long so haven't included it here. Here is the first part:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('smApp')
        .directive('smFormDob', smFormDob);

    smFormDob.$inject = ['angular', 'moment'];

    function smFormDob(angular, moment) {

        var controller = function($scope, $timeout) {
```

Comment: `Failed to load template: /app/_common/form-dob/form-dob.tpl.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)` Are you sure there is the template file in that file path?

Comment: Hey @Mr_Green it does work absolutely fine on the dev build and that template does exist there

Comment: have you given relative or absolute path of the template? try and check the path from where is it loading.. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the templateUrl had a / at the beginning and that was causing the issue

Here's the broken:

```
templateUrl: "/app/_common/form-dob/form-dob.tpl.html"
```

Here's the fixed:

```
templateUrl: "app/_common/form-dob/form-dob.tpl.html"
```